# Room: What is the return value of a failed query?

Tags: android, android-room

Consider this small Room database:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int uid;
}

@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid == :uid")
    User get(int uid);
}
```

What is the return value of `UserDao.get` for a `uid` that doesn't exist in the database? Can I reliably test that there is no user with a given `uid`? Like this:

```
if (userDao.get(17) == null) {
```

Or is it discouraged to query the database like this? Should I *always* return a list, even for querys that can at most return one database row? Thus, should `UserDao` look like this:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid == :uid")
    List<User> get(int uid);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room returns null if you query for one object and it is not present in DB. So your approach is okay, but always be sure to not call your DB in the Main Thread. If you query for a List, a list with 0 size is returned if no matching objects found.